# How to connect Python Django to Informix DB on a remote Windows Server

Tags: python, django, pyodbc, informix

I need to connect my Django app to the Informix db
I have an Informix db installed on a VM Windows server 2019 Datacenter
I can access the db through dbvisualiser on my laptop
I installed the Informix client SDK on my laptop in the Programs Files directory

I tried this settings
https://pypi.org/project/django-informixdb/

**In my settings.py **

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_informixdb', 
        'NAME': 'testdb', 
        'SERVER': "ol_test",
        'HOST': '172.20.10.3',
        'PORT': '9092',
        'USER': 'informix',
        'PASSWORD': 'test@12345',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'DRIVER': "C:\\Program Files\\IBM Informix Client-SDK\\bin\\iclit09b.dll", # Or iclit09b.dylib on macOS
            'Setup': "C:\\Program Files\\IBM Informix Client-SDK\\bin\\iclit09b.dll",
            'CPTIMEOUT': 120,
            'CONN_TIMEOUT': 120,
            'ISOLATION_LEVEL': 'READ_UNCOMMITTED',
            'LOCK_MODE_WAIT': 0,
            'VALIDATE_CONNECTION': True,
        },
        'CONNECTION_RETRY': {
            'MAX_ATTEMPTS': 10,
        },
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'testdb',
            'CREATE_DB': False
        }
    }
}
```

**I got this error**
C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\bdm_reporting_app\bdm_reporting_app\settings.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\bas
e.py", line 282, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", l
ine 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\bas
e.py", line 263, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django_informixdb\base.py",
line 251, in get_new_connection
self.connection = self._get_connection_with_retries(connection_string, conn_params)
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django_informixdb\base.py",
line 299, in _get_connection_with_retries
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=conn_params["AUTOCOMMIT"],
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no def
ault driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_i
nner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py"
, line 64, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\comm
ands\runserver.py", line 137, in inner_run
self.check_migrations()
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base
.py", line 564, in check_migrations
executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\execut
or.py", line 18, in **init**
self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader
.py", line 58, in **init**
self.build_graph()
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader
.py", line 235, in build_graph
self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\record
er.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
if self.has_table():
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\record
er.py", line 57, in has_table
with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", l
ine 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\bas
e.py", line 323, in cursor
return self._cursor()
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\bas
e.py", line 299, in _cursor
self.ensure_connection()
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", l
ine 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\bas
e.py", line 281, in ensure_connection
with self.wrap_database_errors:
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 9
1, in **exit**
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\bas
e.py", line 282, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", l
ine 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\bas
e.py", line 263, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django_informixdb\base.py",
line 251, in get_new_connection
self.connection = self._get_connection_with_retries(connection_string, conn_params)
File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django_informixdb\base.py",
line 299, in _get_connection_with_retries
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=conn_params["AUTOCOMMIT"],
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found a
nd no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The error `Data source name not found and no def ault driver specified` indicates that the ODBC driver manager is unable to find the DSN or the driver.
The location of your CSDK (`Program Files`) suggest you are using a 64-bit CSDK (and a 64-ODBC driver) so for it to work, your Python needs to be 64-bit.
Looking at the django extension (base.py) it looks like it can use both, 32-bit and 64-bits, but I'm not 100% the code is right. The name of the 32-bit Informix ODBC driver is `IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER` not `IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (32-bit)`
Try installing a 32-bit CSDK (e.g 4.10.TC10)